# Html2Canvas not rendering the Font Awsome Icon in iOS

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas and jspdf to generate pdf. Everthing is working fine in Desktop and Android but Font Awsome Icon is not rendering in iOS . I have created a fiddle that fiddle is working in desktop and Android but same fiddle is breaking in iOS. Please help.

Fiddle Link :  https://jsfiddle.net/j09qd4xm/36/

```
HTML :

<div id="target">

<div style="position:relative;" class="noteclasscontainer" >
   <span style="font-size: 60px;" class="glyphicon">&#xe022;

      <span style="color:white;font-size: 21px; position: absolute; top: 16px;left:10px;">dd</span>
   </span>
</div>

</div>
<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>

JS: 

window.takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {

        width:320,
        height:220
    }).then(function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        });
}

CSS : 

button{
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
 .icon-diamond:before {
     content: "\e943";
    }
```

Version :

Html2Canvas : 1.0.0-alpha.12

jspdf : 1.4.1

Comment: As far as I know you need to base64encode it as an image in order for it to display.

Comment: @TPHughes, Thanks for the reply , I have converted the canvas to Base64encode and put it as image in the below fiddle. Icon comes in the browser but not in the iOS.
Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/j09qd4xm/51/

Comment: maybe this can help https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/364#issuecomment-39587766

Answer (score 0):

This pull request fixed it for me: [niklasvh/html2canvas#1649](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/pull/1649). I manually patched the change to my minified JS file.